# Problem in getting object from JSONArray in PostgreSQL using Hibernate

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to retrieve an object from a JsonArray of query return value from PostgreSql  database using hibernate in spring boot application. But i am facing an exception with **'>' is unexpected token**, though my query working perfectly in pgAdmin4 Query Tool, the following my code snippet.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public String getItemById(Long id) {
    String result = (String) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT JSON_AGG(items)->>0 AS item FROM items WHERE id=:id").setParameter("id", id)
            .getResultList().get(0);

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Exception as follows:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 24 [SELECT JSON_AGG(items)->>0 AS item FROM items WHERE id=:id]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 24 [SELECT JSON_AGG(items)->>0 AS item FROM items WHERE id=:id]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:367)
```

please help to achieve this or suggest me work arounds without changing query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is that `JSON_AGG(items)->>0` syntax?

Comment: A postgres utility function to convert query result to json array of objects.

Comment: I know what the `JSON_AGG` function is. But what is the `->>0` being for? I don't know that syntax. And postgres obviously also ...

Comment: to retrieve first object from json array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API method you are using (`entityManager.createQuery(String)`) is to execute JPQL queries as stated in the javadoc:

> Create an instance of Query for executing a Java Persistence query language statement.

The query you want to execute is a SQL query. You should use the `createNativeQuery(String)` method on `EntityManager`.